# How to make all possible pairing for 2 teams of 3 players

Tags: python

Hi im new here and its my first question :)

Im trying to make algorithm to make all possible sets of pairs of 2 teams (3 players each) [3v3]
if i make math right there should be 6 possible options (3!).

```
TeamA = [p1, p2, p3]
TeamB = [o1, o2, o3]

set1 = [[p1, o1], [p2, o2], [p3, o3]]
set2 = [[p1, o2], [p2, o3], [p3, o1]]
set3 = [[p1, o3], [p2, o1], [p3, o2]]
set4 = [[p1, o1], [p2, o3], [p3, o2]]
set5 = [[p1, o3], [p2, o2], [p3, o1]]
set6 = [[p1, o2], [p2, o1], [p3, o3]]
```

Is there a way to make it with algorithm?
im want to implement it in python/django

Comment: This is simply an algorithms/data structures question, so it doesn't have any tie to Django (which is a web framework).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved with [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from itertools import permutations

TeamA = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3']
TeamB = ['o1', 'o2', 'o3']

result = []
for perm in permutations(TeamA):
    result.append(list(zip(perm, TeamB)))

for res in result:
    print(res)
```

notice that `result` is a list of lists, where each one is a list of combinations like you asked

The output of this code would be:

```
[('p1', 'o1'), ('p2', 'o2'), ('p3', 'o3')]
[('p1', 'o1'), ('p3', 'o2'), ('p2', 'o3')]
[('p2', 'o1'), ('p1', 'o2'), ('p3', 'o3')]
[('p2', 'o1'), ('p3', 'o2'), ('p1', 'o3')]
[('p3', 'o1'), ('p1', 'o2'), ('p2', 'o3')]
[('p3', 'o1'), ('p2', 'o2'), ('p1', 'o3')]
```

Comment: Thank You! its so cool! I dont know that zip do but i will check it :)

Comment: No problem! I linked some documentations in the post for you or anyone reading this in the future. cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Something along the following should work:

```
for a in ['a1','a2','a3']:
    for b in ['b1','b2','b3']:
        res.append( [a,b] )
```

Comment: Close, but this doesn't do what OP wanted